# i have win32 dll in vc6 and call on c# with parameter char*?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, visual-c++-6

This vc6 code :

```
MCASMARTMANAGER_API int  __stdcall reqeustKey_test(char* prKey)
{    
    Xhandeler.GetPrimaryKey(prKey);
    return 0;
}

prKey = "AB472EDB9012"
```

And this C# code:

```
[DllImport(McaSmartManagerDllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string reqeustKey_test([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr), In, Out] string prKey);
var key_ = new string(' ', 17);
_strPrimaryKey = McaSmartNativeCommand.reqeustKey_test(key_);
```

Runtime I received on key_  {'い㠶㐵䘷䘰䉆ㄴ㌰'}. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that should be a `LPStr` instead of `LPWStr`. Also... how do you marshal a return value of `string` from an `int`??? I think your code should be using `ref` for your `string prKey` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, "request" is misspelled.

Second, a c# string is unicode (16 bit). A VC6 char* is ASCII (8 bit). Your MarshalAs should be using `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)`

Third, your return type isn't a string, it's an int, and should be marshaled as `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)`,

Comment: when in use UnmanagedType.LPStr return '             ' is empty !?!!?

Comment: As Alvin Wong pointed out, you also should be using a ref string (or an out string, more likely) if you want to set the value of `prKey`